# Org-babel's `call` functionality wraps all results in quotes

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Using org-babel source blocks, I can name a block and call it later. When I evaluate the block itself, I get a bare value:

```
#+name: demo
#+BEGIN_SRC python
return 5
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: demo
: 5
```

But if I `call` the block, the result is always in quotes:

```
#+call: demo()

#+RESULTS:
: "5"
```

How on *earth* do you change this behavior? I've messed with `org-babel-inline-results-wrap`, to no avail.

Comment: Using your exact example, I always obtain a simple unquoted 5. Apart from that, be aware that you can put modifiers to the CALL statement (:results, etc.) exactly as you can on the SRC block (look up in the manual): `#+CALL: <name>[<inside header arguments>](<arguments>) <end header arguments>`.

Comment: Yep. I've tried every flag I can provide to the `call` -- `:results verbatim` for instance. And, I've never seen an instance in which someone _else's_ `call` output was quoted. So my conclusion is: it is configurable somehow! But I cannot, for the life of me, figure out _how_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a side effect of `:results verbatim` *specifically* on `call` blocks. Vis:

```
#+name: demo
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results verbatim
return 5
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: demo
: 5

#+call: demo() :results value

#+RESULTS:
: 5

#+call: demo() :results verbatim

#+RESULTS:
: "5"
```

Frankly, I've no idea why this is the case, but at least it's here in case anyone else runs in to it. (I use `:results verbatim` very commonly on src blocks, so.)

Comment: I can reproduce it, now. But it requires for me `verbatim` on the original src block as well as on the call block. This looks to me like a bug that should be posted to the mailing list.